# how to maintain authentication state across domains using firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase authentication right now and I'm trying to make a website where the authentication is on a different domain, for example:

```
www.example.com
and
subdomain.example.com
both contain features

They both redirect to
accounts.example.com
to login
```

How can I maintain the authentications state between domains?